# Wofstream при попытки записи кирилицы обрывает поток

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, кодировка, utf-8

Написал приложение на `Visual C++ 2010 express`. Выяснилось что в выходной файл также должны писаться и кирилица. Файл должен быть в кодировки `utf-8`. Заменил
`ofstream` на `owstream`. И если раньше просто выходила неверная кодировка, то теперь при попытки записать строку содержащую кирилицу. Поток обрывается на начале кирилице. (Файл `XML`) Посоветуйте как правильно работать с кирилицей.
Вот куски кода.

```
...  
wofstream xml;  
...  
xml.open("output.xml");  
...  
xml << "path=\""<< fname <<"\" "; // < тут происходит обрыв потока... например строку вида "D:\backup\section один" пишет в файл как D:\backup\section и все дальше в файл ничего не попадает.  
...
```

Попробовал следующий упрощенный вариант... результат тот же, пишет только латиницу.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
wofstream xml;
wstring s0 = L"example cyrilic and latin text Кириллица и латинский текст";
xml.open("output.txt");
xml << L"example cyrilic and latin text Кириллица и латинский текст" << endl;
//xml << s0 << endl; <-тут такой же результат как и выше... записывается только латиница.
return 0;
}
```

Попробовал добавить setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");... результат прежний.

Да в тестовом упрощенном видно... в полной версии.. (листинг большой и разбит на несколько файлов) проблема осталась...
Вышел из положения вернувшись обратно к ofstream. И пишу строки использую cp2utf....

```
void cp2utf( char* str, char* res ) {
static const long utf[ 256 ] = {
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,
59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,
87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,
111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,1026,1027,8218,
1107,8222,8230,8224,8225,8364,8240,1033,8249,1034,1036,1035,1039,1106,8216,8217,
8220,8221,8226,8211,8212,8250,8482,1113,8250,1114,1116,1115,1119,160,1038,1118,1032,
164,1168,166,167,1025,169,1028,171,172,173,174,1031,176,177,1030,1110,1169,181,182,
183,1105,8470,1108,187,1112,1029,1109,1111,1040,1041,1042,1043,1044,1045,1046,1047,
1048,1049,1050,1051,1052,1053,1054,1055,1056,1057,1058,1059,1060,1061,1062,1063,
1064,1065,1066,1067,1068,1069,1070,1071,1072,1073,1074,1075,1076,1077,1078,1079,
1080,1081,1082,1083,1084,1085,1086,1087,1088,1089,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1095,
    1096,1097,1098,1099,1100,1101,1102,1103
};
int cnt = strlen( str ),
i = 0, j = 0;
for(; i < cnt; ++i ) {
    long c = utf[ (unsigned char) str[ i ] ];
    if( c < 0x80 ) {
    res[ j++ ] = c;
    }
    else if( c < 0x800 ) {
        res[ j++ ] = c >> 6 | 0xc0;
        res[ j++ ] = c & 0x3f | 0x80;
    } 
    else if( c < 0x10000 ) {
        res[ j++ ] = c >> 12 | 0xe0;
        res[ j++ ] = c >> 6 & 0x3f | 0x80;
        res[ j++ ] = c & 0x3f | 0x80;
    } 
}
res[ j ] = '\0';
}
```

Всем спасибо за помощь. К сожалению проблему с wofstream не решил. Необходимого функционала добился способом описанным выше.

Comment: @Сфинкс, а `fname` у  Вас какого типа?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14637/UTF-8-With-C-in-a-Portable-Way

Comment: @VladD, полезная библиотека (или только один utf.h ?).

 Только, боюсь, ТС она в перекодировке cp1251 (подозреваю, что у него `char *fname` с cp1251) в utf-8 не поможет.

Comment: @avp: ТС пишет, что «Файл должен быть в кодировки utf-8.». Для `wstream`'ов используется не `string`, a `wstring`, так что проблем с внутренней кодировкой быть по идее не должно.

Comment: СТОООООП! Что ж вы в `wstream` пишете `char*`? Надо `wchat_t*`. (` L"path=\""` и т. д.)

Comment: fname имеет тип wstring. Вариант VlaDа сегодня опробую, и отпишусь. Его же ссылку думаю буду использовать только в крайнем случае. Если другие варианты не сработают.

Comment: Думаю, setlocale() в utf-8 нужен.

Comment: @avp stackoverflow посоветовал ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104329/unable-to-write-a-stdwstring-into-wofstream ). Я подправил

     #include <locale>
     #include <fstream>
     using namespace std;
     int main(int argc, char* argv[])
     {
        locale::global(locale(""));
        wofstream xml;
        wstring s0(L"example cyrilic and latin text Кириллица и латинский текст");
        xml.open("output.txt");
        xml << s0 << endl;
        return 0;
     }

Вроде всё видно.

Comment: @alexlz, точно. (пришлось удалить прошлый комментарий (лимит-с!)).

    @Сфинкс, у меня та же фигня (даже в линуксе) с wofstream.

    Не знаю, может лучше вручную (скажем, iconv()-ом (или вообще самому) перекодировать байты с русским в utf-8) и писать обычным байтовым потоком.


Кстати, посмотрел в книжке. Потоку можно установить "локальную" локализацию (действует только на него)

      wofstream xml;
      xml.imbue(locale(""));

После этого тоже работает.

Comment: Нашел решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859020/windows-unicode-c-stream-output-failure/9869272#9869272 Может кому-то пригодится :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Сфинкс](/users/1367/%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%81), комментарии кончились, поэтому в ответе.

Вы несомненно поступили правильно. На практике я бы сделал так же (только на чистом Си, но дело не в этом.)

Просто странно, что с С++ не получилось. Конечно, у меня пример из линукса (пришлось доставить ru_RU.cp1251 локаль), по умолчанию у меня en_US.UTF-8. Но в принципе, в винде д.б. utf локаль, например та же "en_US.utf-8",
так что пример может пригодиться.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  cout << "Hi\n";
  wofstream os;
  os.open("test.ws");
  os.imbue(locale(av[1] && *av[1] == 'c' ? "ru_RU.cp1251" : "en_US.utf-8"));
  os << "1 aa xaxa xoxo wofstream\n" << L"zz рус бук\n";
  os.close();

  cout << "End\n";
  return 0;
}
```

А вот результат

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ g++ wofstream.cpp
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Hi
End
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ cat test.ws 
1 aa xaxa xoxo wofstream
zz рус бук
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./a.out cp1251
Hi
End
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ cat test.ws 
1 aa xaxa xoxo wofstream
zz ��� ��
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 test.ws 
1 aa xaxa xoxo wofstream
zz рус бук
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

Хочу отметить, что в тексте программы русские буквы набиты в utf-8. Если убрать `L` перед  константой, то перекодировки (если ее задавать) не будет.

Также никакой перекодировки нет, если заменить `wofstream` на `ofstream` (естественно модификатор `L` для `ofstream` надо убрать).